# Wave equation regularity

Tags: linear-pde, regularity, hyperbolic-pde

I have an equation of the type

$$\hat{\rho} u_{tt}-\hat{E}u_{xx}=f(x,t)$$

for $x\in (0,1)$ and $t>0$, where $\hat{\rho}$ and $\hat{E}$ are constants, $u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$, $u(x,0)=p(x)$, $u_t(x,0)=q(x)$, $p,q,f\in C^\infty([0,1]\times[0,T])$ and $p(0)=p(1)=0$.

Under which conditions can I assure that $u(\cdot,t)\in C^3([0,1]\times[0,T])$ at least?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your solution is already $C^ \infty$ by your assumptions.